# Parsing only some variables with heredoc or nowdoc

Tags: php, string, heredoc, nowdoc

Using heredoc or nowdoc, how could I create $sting?

```
$x_value=2;
$string='$x='.$x_value.';';
exit($string);  //$x=2;
```

PS. I am aware of the slippery slope of script like this

Comment: Without even needing to use heredoc/nowdoc `$string="\$x={$x_value};";`

Comment: Thanks Mark, but I showed just a very small example, and wanted to use heredoc.

Comment: @Mark.  Thanks.  Escaped it just like you showed it, and it works perfect!

Comment: On this site, we discourage answers being edited into questions. Instead, you're encouraged to post an answer to your own question. That way, people can see at a glance that the question has an answer.

Comment: @IMSoP  I will edit it.  Just didn't want to take credit for an answer which Mark's comment was the inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Per Mark's comment, the value which shouldn't be parsed should be escaped:

```
$x_value=2;
$string = <<<EOD
\$x=$x_value;
EOD;
exit($string);
```